# Push Down Menu in Joomla! 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm in search of a good menu/navigation extension for Joomla! 2.5 which enables me to push down the whole content below the navigation bar at the top, when clicking on a top level menu item.

Example seen on ibm.com

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are few free modules out there in Joomla where you can get the same push down effect like your given ibm.com site. One of such example is the JA top panel which is a joomlart module:

[ja top panel module link](http://demo.joomlart.com/extensions15/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=135&Itemid=123)

and the example is shown on the following Joomlart template named by JA social. Here you can see the top panel navigation is working exactly like ibm push down and once you installed it on your template then link all your menu with it. [joomlart template JASocial link](http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#ja_social)